# Noise and fireflies in glass, even with high number of samples

Tags: rendering

I have rendered the following image by 5000 sample sand I used progressive rendering, but it still has this disturbing image.

What can I do to get a better image?

[image]

Comment: Try dropping glass/reflective light bounces...

Comment: You are trying to do caustics with simple path-tracer and you have a small size light-source. You can only lower the quality to get faster render. You are using the wrong tool for the job. You need a bi-directional renderer, try Lux render for example.

Comment: Please show the materials you are using for the jar.

Comment: will denoising work